# Declaring Databasename in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am preparing a group of sql queries for a dashboard. I want to declare the database name at the beginning so that the queries will work on the database specified on top without making any changes in the underlying code

Original query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Check.dbo.Dates_table
```

The query I want:

```
DECLARE @Databasename VARCHAR(200)
SET @Databasename = 'Check.dbo'

SELECT * FROM @Databasename.Dates_table
```

Comment: Why don't you simply change the connection or issue a `USE [somedb]` command? Why try to pass it as a parameter? In any case, the database *isn't* a value so it can't be treated as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "USE" operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188366.aspx

```
use Check

SELECT * FROM dbo.Dates_table
```